# Can't set SharedPreferences In AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to set the shared preferences in my asynctask but it seems to not be working. Could anyone help me out. I tried a billion things already

Button/ASYNC Code:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        private ProgressDialog cancelDialog = null;
        int valid;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    valid = api.validateLogin(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                    return null;
                }


                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    cancelDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                    cancelDialog.setMessage("Validating Username & Password");
                    cancelDialog.show();

                    super.onPreExecute();
                } 

            @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                    cancelDialog.cancel();
                    if(valid == 2){
                        SharedPreferences savedSession = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("xdaeaf", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        savedSession.edit().putString("username", username.getText().toString());
                        try {
                            String passtext = MCrypt.bytesToHex(mcrypt.encrypt(password.getText().toString()));
                            savedSession.edit().putString("password", ""+passtext);
                            savedSession.edit().commit();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                            //TODO:
                    }

                        //TODO: 
                    }else{
                        //TODO:
                    }

                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                }

            }.execute();    
        }
    });
```

My accessing code:

```
    SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences("xdaeaf", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = savedSession.getString("username", "");
    String password = savedSession.getString("password", "");
    System.out.println("username:"+username+" password:"+password);
```

I checked if I was passing on empty variables to the putSTring but it is passing values to it. Its just not saving. When I rerun the accessing code it just prints out "Username: password:". The values are blank when trying to re access it.

Comment: You never commit your editor. it is not saved until you commit the editor.

Comment: Just wondering, what is this "xdaeaf" SharedPreferences? Did you come up with the name or are you using it from somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
savedSession.edit().putString("username", username.getText().toString());
```

Every call to edit() returns you a new Editor instance. So you get an instance, make a change and leave it alone. Then you get a second one and commit that without changes, which results in no value changes in the preferences.

```
Editor editor = savedSession.edit();
editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
editor.putString("password", ""+passtext);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call the everytime the `savedSession.edit()` then it will return you different object then you have to call the `commit` method on each to save the values.

So get one instance of the `Editor` like this

```
Editor editor = savedSession.edit();
```

then use this reference to save the values.

Your code should be

```
Editor editor = savedSession.edit();
editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
String passtext = MCrypt.bytesToHex(mcrypt.encrypt(password.getText().toString()));
editor.putString("password", ""+passtext);
editor.commit();
```